# Is there a good off-the-shelf distributed database solution for Postgres (PostgreSQL)?

Tags: database, postgresql, cluster-computing, distributed, distributed-computing

I understand how to join nodes into a cluster, remove them, etc. using Postgres, but I'm wondering if there are any software solutions out there that will manage the complexities for me of having a distributed database across N physical nodes.

Specifically, is there any off-the-shelf solution out there that will handle:

1. N nodes (where N is at least 3) running the distributed database with Q copies where Q is at least 2 and less than or equal to N (for example, if N is 3 and Q is 2, any piece of data must be replicated between 2 physical nodes out of the 3-node cluster).
2. If a node goes down, the distributed database will continue to run in a degraded mode provided that less than Q nodes have gone down.
3. If a node that went down comes back up, the distributed database will automatically sync up the degraded node.
4. Nodes can be added to the distributed database after initial configuration.  This does not necessarily have to trigger a re-balancing, but the node should be considered for placement of new data for the distributed database.
5. Nodes can be removed from the distributed database after initial configuration.  When this occurs, any data on the removed node must be replicated to other nodes so that we can get back to Q good copies online.

Comment: From the FAQ. Aster is actually quite nice. Pricy so.
Q: When will PostgreSQL get database server clustering?
A: We already have it. Since no one type of clustering satisfies all needs, we have several different clustering tools which take various clustering approaches. The open source projects PostgresXC and Postgres-XL are available, as well as open source forks and proprietary tools such as Greenplum Database, Aster Data, CitusData and several others. Also, PostgreSQL is supported by filesystem-based clustering systems for failover, including ones from Red Hat, Microsoft, Veritas and Oracle

Comment: http://2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/bdr/

Comment: BDR only supports asynchronius replication (and if it supported synchronous, it would be PERFECT from what I've seen so far about it).  I should have mentioned the nodes in question will be all local connected over low-latency 10GigE.  Eventual consistency isn't good enough.  Looks like pgPool might provide the solution I'm looking for, or Postgres-XL, but it doesn't look like Postgres-XL is being maintained much at this point...